# Por qual meio pode-se remover célula dinâmica inserida na tabela HTML

Tags: javascript, table, dom, dinâmico

## Script

```js
        var opt = document;

        function inserirLinha(id) {
            var newRow = opt.createElement('tr');
            newRow.insertCell(0).innerHTML = '<input type="button" value="X" onclick="removeLinha(this)" />';
            newRow.insertCell(1).innerHTML = 'REMOVER';
            newRow.insertCell(2).innerHTML = 'A LINHA';
            opt.getElementById(id).appendChild(newRow);
            return false;
        }

 function removeLinha(id) {
            var apagar = opt.getElementsByTagName(id);
            apagar.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(apagar.parentNode);
 }
```

```html
<center>
    <form onsubmit="return inserirLinha('minhaTabela')">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <tbody id="minhaTabela"></tbody>
                </tr>
            </table>
        <input type="submit" value="Adicionar" name="submit">
    </form>
</center>
```

O script acima tem duas funções distintas, uma delas à saber `inserirLinha` que inclui uma nova linha na tabela ja predefinida no HTML, mas a função `removeLinha` não esta cumprindo o seu papel, por quê?

No *console* do navegador, acusa:

> **TypeError: apagar is null**

O *Debbuger* aponta para:

```
apagar.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(apagar.parentNode);
```

Tai um problema que pouco me mostra o quê resolver.

Comment: Agora estou sem tempo de ver, mas o que eu acho é que no `onclick="removeLinha(this)"`, o `this` se refere ao objeto `input` (não a um ID), por isso que `getElementById` retorna null.

Comment: E para apagar uma linha de uma tabela, talvez seja melhor usar `deleteRow` (ao invés de `parentNode`, que dependendo da estrutura da página, pode variar muito o resultado)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer assim:

```js
var opt = document;

function inserirLinha(id) {
  var newRow = opt.createElement('tr');
  newRow.insertCell(0).innerHTML = '<input type="button" value="X" onclick="removeLinha(this)" />';
  newRow.insertCell(1).innerHTML = 'REMOVER';
  newRow.insertCell(2).innerHTML = 'A LINHA';
  opt.getElementById(id).appendChild(newRow);
  return false;
}

function removeLinha(element) {
  element.parentNode.parentNode.outerHTML = '';
}
```

```html
<center>
  <form onsubmit="return inserirLinha('minhaTabela')">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <tbody id="minhaTabela"></tbody>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Adicionar" name="submit">
  </form>
</center>
```

O `this` passado é o elemento HTML então use `parentNode` duas vezes, o primeiro para pegar o `td` e o segundo a `tr`, e sete o atributo `outerHTML` para uma string vazia, isso o excluirá

Comment: Se você precisar desse `id` para alguma outra coisa use a solução do @MatheusReis se não pode usar a minha por ser mais simples e não ira precisar se preocupar com os ids

Answer (score 2):

O problema é que você está tentando usar a função `getElementById()`, mas não é encontrado nenhum elemento. O `this` que você está passando para a função não é um id. Logo, é retornada uma referência null.

O que você deveria fazer é definir um id pra cada linha!

```
newRow.id = "linha" + (linhas+1)
```

Sendo `linhas` uma variável global, que irá contar a quantidade de linhas até o momento. Então, após definir o id, você deve passar ele como parâmetro pra função remove linha.

```
function inserirLinha(id) {
   var newRow = opt.createElement('tr');
   newRow.id = "linha" + (linhas+1)
   newRow.insertCell(0).innerHTML = '<input type="button" value="X" onclick="removeLinha(' + newRow.id + ')" />';
   newRow.insertCell(1).innerHTML = 'REMOVER';
   newRow.insertCell(2).innerHTML = 'A LINHA';
   opt.getElementById(id).appendChild(newRow);
   return false;
}
```

Outro detalhe: Você estava fazendo `apagar.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(apagar)`. Porém, a linha está apenas um nível do elemento `apagar`. Então, basta fazer `apagar.parentNode.removeChild(apagar)`

Código completo abaixo:

```js
 var opt = document;
 linhas = 0

function inserirLinha(id) {
            var newRow = opt.createElement('tr');
            newRow.id = "linha" + (linhas+1)
            linhas += 1
            newRow.insertCell(0).innerHTML = '<input type="button" value="X" onclick="removeLinha('+ newRow.id + ')" />';
            newRow.insertCell(1).innerHTML = 'REMOVER';
            newRow.insertCell(2).innerHTML = 'A LINHA';
            opt.getElementById(id).appendChild(newRow);
            return false;
}

function removeLinha(id) {
    var apagar = opt.getElementById(id.id);
    apagar.parentNode.removeChild(apagar);
}
```

```html
<center>
    <form onsubmit="return inserirLinha('minhaTabela')">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <tbody id="minhaTabela"></tbody>
                </tr>
            </table>
        <input type="submit" value="Adicionar" name="submit">
    </form>
</center>
```

Comment: Agora, com tanta diversidade de repostas ficou  até mesmo difícil definir o voto, vou analisar todas respostas e suas explicações pra eu votar, ja que todas são úteis. Grato por sua correção.

Comment: A comunidade é boa por isso.. diferentes soluções para um mesmo problema! Sempre às ordens :)

Answer (score 1):

*apagar is null* é uma pista; pode ser que o `id` sendo passado para `removerLinha` não exista no documento, ou está com erro de ortografia.

Veja também que `removerLinhas` não verifica se o que está sendo apagando é realmente uma linha, mas sim, apaga qualquer coisa que tenha um parentesco avô-neto, apagando o pai e o neto, este último com o `id` informado.

Troque a seguinte linha:

```
newRow.insertCell(0).innerHTML = '<input type="button" value="X" onclick="removeLinha(this)" />';
```

por

```
var ids = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) + 1);
newRow.insertCell(0).innerHTML = '<input id="id' + ids +  '" type="button" value="X" onclick="removeLinha(\"id' + ids + '\")" />';
```

Comment: Não, tô usando `Math.floor` e `Math.random` para gerar IDs de botão aleatoriamente